# JMeter stops the Thread Group before the duration, when using Throughput Shaping Timer values from properties file - "No further RPS schedule" message

Tags: jmeter

I have a script with multiple Thread Groups. As can be seen from below image, script has:

- setUp Thread Group which reads the properties file
- Token Generation and Pre Requisite which is used for Login and Token Generation
- 3rd Thread Group ...APIs which is used for API execution with Throughput Shaping Timer

[image]

I am keeping the duration in properties file as **18000** seconds, shown in below image:

[image]

Throughput Shaping Timer settings shown below:

[image]

Now, during execution sometimes the Test runs for complete 5 hours, sometimes it runs for 30 minutes, 1 hour, 2 hours etc.

JMeter log file shows below message, start and end time also shown in the image. In current scenario, **tests stops after 1.5 hours**:
[image]

[image]

Could you please help to solve this issue and the Test should run for the duration specified in properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Throughput Shaping Timer source code](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/7d7e59c6c46964e8bea49783ea4a983a7aa95eea/plugins/tst/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/timers/VariableThroughputTimer.java#L136) I can see that `No further RPS schedule, asking threads to stop...` message can be printed to the log **only if "Duration" is exceeded**

So I would recommend checking your `duration` property value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) combination.

If it has the anticipated value of `18000` ensure that you don't change the property anywhere in the runtime.

You can also i[ncrease JMeter logging verbosity](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) to [DEBUG level](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm)  and see if you can spot anything suspicious in jmeter.log file

Other test elements which can be used for controlling the throughput are:

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

so you might want to try them out instead of the Throughput Shaping Timer